# How can i handle LayoutUpdated or stop a control rendring in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, rendering

i want to cancel or stop or handle rendering(or drawing) a WPF Element for lower cpu usage(cancel all forever animations and rendering in background or collapsed visibility items for use best performance in my app).

i read all [Optimizing WPF Application Performance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970683.aspx)

```
void MainWindow_LayoutUpdated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = true;//can i handle an object rendering?
    }
```

Comment: What have you found? what is the problem?

Comment: i have a datagrid and that are progressbars items... these are in an expander and isindeterminate = true. i want if expander is collapsed progressbars rendering stop... but it is not stop and my application cpu usage is very high... if i remove progressbars from application, cpu usage is lower..and problems elsewhere in rendering.i want to manage rendering from wpf app.

Comment: Your question doesn't have enough details, you should provide some code that shows how your `ProgressBars` are working.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[LayoutUpdated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.layoutupdated.aspx) is not going to help you at all. It is an event that fires on all UI elements associated with a `Dispatcher` *after* a full layout pass has completed, meaning the work is already done.

You have a few options, depending on what your goal is.

**Hide the Element**

If you don't want the element to be visible or perform any layout, then you can set its `Visibility` property to `Collapsed`. It should skip most of its layout logic and all of its rendering logic while it is collapsed.

**Remove the Element**

Removing the element from the visual tree is a sure way to keep it from doing anything. You can add it back later if you need to. The process for how to do this depends a lot on how your code is currently setup.

**Reduce the Performance Cost of the Element**

If the element is expensive because it is doing a lot of work, you could look into optimizing it in general, and/or look into disconnecting its event listeners and bindings during the time when you don't want it doing work.

**Pause UI Processing**

If you want to temporarily pause all UI processing while you perform some operation (to prevent reentrancy), you can use [Dispatcher.DisableProcessing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.disableprocessing.aspx).  Note that this will disable UI processing for the entire thread, not just the processing of a specific element.

```
using (Dispatcher.DisableProcessing())
{
    // Do work while the dispatcher processing is disabled.
}
```

**A Static Picture of the Element**

If you want to *permanently* disable all processing of an element, I don't know of a way to do that while still keeping it visible on the screen. However, you could use a [RenderTargetBitmap](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.rendertargetbitmap.aspx) to render the element to an `ImageSource` and then replace the original element with an [Image](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.image.aspx) element that has its `Source` property set to the bitmap.

```
RenderTargetBitmap target = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)element.RenderSize.Width, (int)element.RenderSize.Height, 96.0, 96.0, PixelFormats.Default);
target.Render(element);
image.Source = target;
```

Now you basically have a "picture" of the element in place of where the original element was.